# How to get object writer with both pretty print and with a json view from objectmapper?

Tags: json, jackson, objectmapper

I need to create json with both pretty print and also using JsonView. 
How to do the same from jackson objectmapper?
I get following error when I try to use both properties.

> Error:The method writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter() is undefined for the
>   type ObjectWriter.

My code:

```
objectMapper.writerWithView(View.ConfigJson.class).writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(file, value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to enable [SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#INDENT_OUTPUT) on `ObjectMapper`:

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Or use `withDefaultPrettyPrinter` method:

```
mapper
    .writerWithView(View.ConfigJson.class)
    .withDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValue(System.out, map);
```

You need to notice that `writer*` methods are declared in `ObjectMapper` and return `ObjectWriter` instance. Since that, you can use `with*` methods which are declared in `ObjectWriter`.